Status call back not working in twilio with python SDK
Yes I am handling a POST, and can handle url encoded form data, unlike the other SO questions.
I create a sms via twilio Python SDK like this:
from twilio.rest import Client

edge = None  # 'roaming' (does not work), 'dublin' (not reliable)
client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_TOKEN, edge=edge)

twilio_message = client.messages.create(
    to=cleaned_to_tel,
    body=trimmed_body,
    from_=TWILIO_FROM,
    status_callback="https://www.example.com/twilio/api/delivery-callback/",
)

But the callback url is never hit. If I test the callback end point with:
curl -X POST https://www.example.com/twilio/api/delivery-callback/ -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "SmsSid=SM2xxxxxx&SmsStatus=sent&MessageStatus=sent&To=+1512zzzyyyy&MessageSid=SM2xxxxxx&AccountSid=AC40??????????????????????????????&From=+1512xxxyyyy&ApiVersion=2021-01-05"

It works and logs the result using this view:
class DeliveryCallBackView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []  # disables authentication
    permission_classes = []  # disables permission

    def post(self, request):
        from base.models import SysEvent
        SysEvent.objects.create(
            name='twilio_delivery_callback',
            note=str(request),
        )
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

But it appears twilio never calls my status callback, even though the sms is delivered.
